# How to draw gizmos in iOS with MetalKit & Metal?

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

Is there any way to integrate SceneKit object gizmos in Metal or do I have to implement it from scratch? I want to rotate, scale and translate object in a simple way with gizmo like Blender style. I've researched for some libraries but OpenGL has a lot more options than Metal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't integrate SceneKit object gizmos, because the are no bridge APIs. Gizmos themselves are just primitives, I don't think it will be difficult for you to write your own solution.

Comment: So, I need to import .obj models and texture them with gesture interaction, right?

Comment: Yes it is right.